# how to efficiently do calculations in R that's based on previous row?

Tags: r

I have dataframe that looks like this:

```
       time    open   close    high     low quantity    vwap                date
1253687 1388552400 741.601 744.000 744.900 741.601    1.957 744.160 2014-01-01 00:00:00
1253688 1388552460 744.000 744.000 744.000 744.000    0.000 744.000 2014-01-01 00:01:00
1253689 1388552520 744.900 744.900 744.900 744.890    3.197 744.897 2014-01-01 00:02:00
1253690 1388552580 744.889 741.803 744.889 741.803    5.511 742.593 2014-01-01 00:03:00
1253691 1388552640 744.881 744.881 744.881 744.881    0.160 744.881 2014-01-01 00:04:00
1253692 1388552700 744.881 741.803 744.881 741.803    1.010 741.833 2014-01-01 00:05:00
```

I want to create a new column where it stores the lowest low in the last 3 minutes and a new column that stores the highest high in the last 3 minutes.

The dataframe has 100k rows, so doing operation by looking at individual rows and looping through all the rows is slow, what's a fast way to do it? (similar to diff() function where it calculates the difference of rows quickly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is regularly spaced, so you can use rolling window functions.  For example take a look at `rollmaxr()` from the `zoo` package.

```
library(zoo)
df$High3Min <- rollmaxr(df$high, 3, fill=NA)
df$Low3Min <- (-1)*rollmaxr((-1)*df$low, 3, fill=NA)
```

There are other rolling window functions in various packages if you need something more general than min and max in the future.

If you want it to look backward and not at the contemporaneous row, you can lag each vector once using your lag method of choice before putting them in the dataframe.